# twig random if else

Tags: random, twig

I try to learn Twig and I've got the next sample

```
{{ random(['1', '2', '3']) }}   

{% if random.1 %}
    <img src="../1.jpg"  alt="banner" class="img-responsive" >
{% elseif random.2 %}
    <img src="../2.jpg"  alt="banner" class="img-responsive" >
{% else %}
    <img src="../3.jpg"  alt="banner" class="img-responsive" >
{% endif %}
```

There displays one number 0 , 1 or 3
(number should not be displayed)

Further result of image is always 3.jpg

Someone can help me find the way to write the right code ?

Comment: `{% set rand = random([1, 2, 3,]) %}{% if rand == 1 %}...`

Answer (score 1):

@DarkBee 's answer is correct. This is how you would code it:

```
{% set rand = random([1, 2, 3,]) %}

{% if rand == 1 %}
    <img src="../1.jpg"  alt="banner" class="img-responsive" >
{% elseif rand == 2 %}
    <img src="../2.jpg"  alt="banner" class="img-responsive" >
{% else %}
    <img src="../3.jpg"  alt="banner" class="img-responsive" >
{% endif %}
```

Here is the working twigfiddle for you to try it out: https://twigfiddle.com/5fhr6x

Comment: Checkmark besides my answer if it is correct. Thanks!